# How to check if an objects property exists in another one too?

Tags: javascript

I have two different objects and I want to if at least one property of second objects' matches with the first one, I want to return true. If not, return false. I've tried .hasOwnProperty and .keys methods but couldn't handle it. Here an example code below. Thanks.

```
let propchecker = (a,b) =>{
    if(/* at least one property matches exact */){
        return true;
     }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

let origin = {name: "John", surname: "Doe"};

let first = {name: "John", surname: "Roe" };
let second = {name: "Jane", surname: "Doe"};
let third = {name: "Richard", surname: "Roe"};

console.log(propchecker(origin,first)); //Should return True.
console.log(propchecker(origin,second)); //Should return True.
console.log(propchecker(origin,third)); //Should return False.
```

Comment: Should it be as generic as possible or ist checking name and surname enough?

Comment: generic should be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there maybe shorter solution but this works fine

```js
let propchecker = (a,b) =>{
for (let key in a) {
  for (let key2 in b ){
    if(a[key] == b[key2]){
     return true
   }
 }
}
return false
}

let origin = {name: "John", surname: "Doe"};

let first = {name: "John", surname: "Roe" };
let second = {name: "Jane", surname: "Doe"};
let third = {name: "Richard", surname: "Roe"};

console.log(propchecker(origin,first)); //Should return True.
console.log(propchecker(origin,second)); //Should return True.
console.log(propchecker(origin,third)); //
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the keys of one object using `Object.keys()` and then use `some()` on it.

```js
let propchecker = (a,b) => Object.keys(a).some(x => a[x] === b[x])

let origin = {name: "John", surname: "Doe"};

let first = {name: "John", surname: "Roe" };
let second = {name: "Jane", surname: "Doe"};
let third = {name: "Richard", surname: "Roe"};

console.log(propchecker(origin,first)); //Should return True.
console.log(propchecker(origin,second)); //Should return True.
console.log(propchecker(origin,third)); //Should return False.
```

Comment: this is the shorter solution nice

Comment: @SirDad Consider accepting he answer if think is best for you.

Comment: yeah of course bro its should be the best answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let propchecker = (a,b) =>{
   result =  false;
   for(let ele in first){
       result  = result  || (a[ele] === b[ele])
    }
   return result
 }

let origin = {name: "John", surname: "Doe"};

let first = {name: "John", surname: "Roe" };
let second = {name: "Jane", surname: "Doe"};
let third = {name: "Richard", surname: "Roe"};

console.log(propchecker(origin,first)); //Should return True.
console.log(propchecker(origin,second)); //Should return True.
console.log(propchecker(origin,third)); //Should return False.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's been answered already, but I'll throw my hat in the ring as well. All these answers are doing pretty much the same thing.

```
let propchecker = (a,b) =>{
    var check = false;
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key) {
        if(a[key] == b[key]) {
            check = true;
        }
    })

    return check;
}

let origin = {name: "John", surname: "Doe"};

let first = {name: "John", surname: "Roe" };
let second = {name: "Jane", surname: "Doe"};
let third = {name: "Richard", surname: "Roe"};

console.log(propchecker(origin,first)); //Should return True.
console.log(propchecker(origin,second)); //Should return True.
console.log(propchecker(origin,third)); //Should return False.
```